# jitter points violin plot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in R which looks like this:

```
Value   group   Dataset
0.00    1   A
0.00    1   A
0.71    1   A
0.00    1   A
185.87  1   A
0.00    1   A
41.24   1   A
177.04  1   A
0.00    1   A
31.23   1   A
1.46    2   A
0.00    2   A
268.37  2   A
0.00    2   A
5.36    2   A
0.00    2   A
0.00    2   A
37.02   2   A
0.00    3   A
147.50  3   A
1.62    3   A
24.26   3   A
152.02  3   A
165.31  3   A
519.40  3   A
546.49  3   A
122.80  3   A
528.28  3   A
228.77  3   A
0.00    1   B
41.24   1   B
177.04  1   B
0.00    1   B
31.23   1   B
371.58  2   B
1103.61 2   B
65.28   2   B
51.02   2   B
78.92   2   B
296.93  2   B
152.02  3   B
165.31  3   B
519.40  3   B
546.49  3   B
122.80  3   B
528.28  3   B
228.77  3   B
```

I want to make a violin plot for Dataset A and B with 3 violin plots for A and 3 for B on the same plot. This is my code in R but I can't seem to get points over the individual violin plots. They are on the middle of the Dataset A and B.

```
ggplot(combined_data, aes(x = factor(Dataset), y = Value, fill = group)) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 1, width = 0.2))
```

Comment: Perhaps try `ggplot(combined_data, aes(x = factor(Dataset), y = Value, fill = factor(group), group = interaction(group, Dataset))) + ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use "sneaky facets" here

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(combined_data, aes(x = factor(group), y = Value, fill = factor(group))) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.4, scale = 'width') +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 1, width = 0.2),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(~Dataset, switch = 'x') +
  scale_x_discrete('Group within dataset', expand = c(0.6, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1', guide = 'none') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background.x = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

[image]